# Buckets using two factors?

Tags: r, dataframe, bucket

I'm looking to create buckets for a project I am working on but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.
I have data on business' log annual profits, log total assets, and whether they went insolvent or not over a time period. What am I being asked to do is create a bucket using the profits and the assets and then say the rate of insolvency per bucket.

Thus far, I am fine with chopping up the data into deciles using the assets but I can't figure out how to chop the data such that I have a range of profits and then chop that into deciles by assets (if that makes sense).

For the chopping into deciles my code looks like so:

```
mydf <- data.frame(Insolve = (my_data$FLAG),
                             profit = (my_data$LOGPNL),
                             assets = (my_data$LOGBAL),
                             )

mydf$decile <- ntile(mydf$assets, 10)
fd2 <- mydf %>% arrange(mydf$decile, decreasing=FALSE)
fd21 <- fd2%>%
  group_by(decile) %>%
  summarise(
    insolvency_n = sum(Insolve),
    assets_mean = mean(assets),
    assets_sd = sd(assets),
    profits_mean = mean(profit),
    profits_sd = sd(profit),
  )

dc1 <- filter(fd2, decile=='1')
dc2 <- filter(fd2, decile=='2')
dc3 <- filter(fd2, decile=='3')
dc4 <- filter(fd2, decile=='4')
dc5 <- filter(fd2, decile=='5')
dc6 <- filter(fd2, decile=='6')
dc7 <- filter(fd2, decile=='7')
dc8 <- filter(fd2, decile=='8')
dc9 <- filter(fd2, decile=='9')
dc10 <- filter(fd2, decile=='10')
```

But considering the problem, I know this isn't the right approach as I am just chopping the data using that one thing.

My question is, using R, how can I bucket my data into a range of profit values (my data range from -30 to +30) and then slice that into deciles using the assets (in the future I may need to slice the assets into a range as well but that's a future problem)?

Cheers!

Comment: Could you please edit the post to include the output from `dput(mydf)`, or `dput(head(mydf))` if your data is relatively large. It should be something beginning with `structure(...`.

Comment: You could do `split(fd2, fd2$decile)`. This will produce a list of data frames, one for each decile. It is best to keep them in a list rather than having 10 separate data frames in your global environment. However, if you really want to do this you could run the line `list2env(setNames(split(fd2, fd2$decile), paste0('dc', 1:10)), .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: @AllanCameron thanks for your reply. This gives me the deciles as data frames, thank you. If I wanted to break down the data differently, for example, cut the original data into a dataframe of profits within a certain range (for instance, all companies with profits between 0 and 10). How could I do that before then using what you have given?